# Does the Transient Fault Handling application block deal with a connection that is currently connected to a federated database?

Tags: .net, azure, database-connection, azure-sql-database, sharding

In Windows Azure we had retry logic, using the Transient Fault Handling Application Block, that worked as expected on our worker roles.
However we recently upgraded our SQL Azure database to be federated and have experienced a few issues since then.

Our worker role is occasionally saying a particular stored procedure doesn't exist. This is the stored procedure we have it checking every second in the Run loop. The role loops through each shard and runs the stored procedure on each sharded database. This all works fine, however very occasionally we get errors in the log stating it can't find the stored procedure with a call stack indicating the TransientFaultHandling connection was retried.

Seeing as our code simply creates a connection (keeping it open) connects to a shard and then executes the stored procedure, I thought the candidate could be that if there is a transient fault and it retries the connection it may end up connected back to the root database instead of the shard it used to be connected too?

My question is does the TransientFaultHandling block correctly account for this and re-connect back to the correct shard when retrying a connection, and if not is there a best practice for doing so?

Thanks
Gareth

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are on the right track; the connection is probably reset to the root database. The Transient Fault Handling block will handle transient errors automatically but is not Federation aware as far as I know.

I wonder how your code is structured. But here is an idea (if that's not what you are already doing): You could use the application block to retry an entire piece of code that includes the connection request, the USE command (for federation) and the stored proc call. So if that fails, everything gets to be retried. You do that by creating a retry policy object (which would be the SQL database transient detection strategy), and call the ExecuteAction method that performs all the work you want done.

Hope this helps.

Herve

Comment: Thanks.That's what I thought, and I am currently doing as you suggested.